# How to Upload Multiple Images of Firebase using Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-image

i'm creating an app where i can upload two pictures alongside some information, however i can't manage to upload two images into the firebase realtime Database. Below is my code please help.

```
public abstract class BaseCreatePostActivity<V extends BaseCreatePostView, P extends BaseCreatePostPresenter<V>>
    extends PickImageActivity<V, P> implements BaseCreatePostView {

protected ImageView imageView;
protected ImageView imageView2;
protected ProgressBar progressBar;
protected EditText titleEditText;
protected EditText descriptionEditText;



@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.base_create_post_activity);
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    titleEditText = findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
    descriptionEditText = findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
    aliasEditText = findViewById(R.id.aliasEditText);


    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> onSelectImageClick(v));

    imageView2.setOnClickListener(k -> onSelectImageClick(k));

    titleEditText.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if (titleEditText.hasFocus() && titleEditText.getError() != null) {
            titleEditText.setError(null);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}

@Override
protected ProgressBar getProgressView() {
    return progressBar;
}

@Override
protected ImageView getImageView() {
    return imageView;
}



@Override
protected void onImagePikedAction() {
    loadImageToImageView(imageUri);
}

@Override
public void setDescriptionError(String error) {
    descriptionEditText.setError(error);
    descriptionEditText.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void setTitleError(String error) {
    titleEditText.setError(error);
    titleEditText.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void setAliasError(String error) {
    aliasEditText.setError(error);
    aliasEditText.requestFocus();
}


@Override
public String getTitleText() {
    return titleEditText.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public String getDescriptionText() {
    return descriptionEditText.getText().toString();
}



@Override
public void requestImageViewFocus() {
    imageView.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void onPostSavedSuccess() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public Uri getImageUri() {
    return imageUri;
}
```

I have tried so much to achieve this but i=I wasn't successful. Any little help will be grateful. Thank you
I have tried so much to achieve this but i=I wasn't successful. Any little help will be grateful. Thank you

Comment: The code you shared shows nothing related to uploading an image to Firebase. I highly recommend checking out the [documentation for Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) for an example, or the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) that shows you how to upload (and read) images in a working app.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Trust me it is easy!